# Animation of loading until image is actually displayed

Tags: javascript

please look at the application I've created https://codepen.io/flowbartek93/pen/pobQvwQ.

As you can see, its about matching cats to their shadow clones on time. But there is one thing I can't do.

I want something like this: After clicking "add cat", loading spinner is displayed and when image is finnaly loaded the spinner disapears.

But I don't know what this time of wating on image to be displayed actually is. So I don't know how to check it. I already know that it's not the entire DIV element or http 200 response. So what it is then ?

Those are two main functions responsible for fetching and displaying cat image and loading animation also. The animation must be run dynamically from Java Script because when hard coded in html and playing with display attribute I find it very hard to accomplish what I want but maybe Im wrong. Please check my codepen to get a greater picture.

```
  function downloadCat() { // 

    const catsUrl = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search";
    fetch(catsUrl).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => displayCat(json[0].url))

}


function displayCat(imgUrl) {
  
    const newCat = document.createElement("div");
    newCat.setAttribute("class", "cat draggable")

    /* Loading */
    const loading = document.createElement('div')

    loading.setAttribute("class", "lds-ring")

    newCat.appendChild(loading);
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const emptyDiv = document.createElement('div');
        loading.appendChild(emptyDiv);
    }

    /* Loading */

    newCat.setAttribute("id", idCounter++);
    newCat.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgUrl + ")";
    catBoard.appendChild(newCat);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`image.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) event, This event handler will be called on the image element when the image has finished loading.

```js
function downloadCat() {
  const catsUrl = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search";
  fetch(catsUrl).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => displayCat(json[0].url))
}


function displayCat(imgUrl) {

  const newCat = document.createElement("div");
  newCat.setAttribute("class", "cat draggable")

  /* Loading */
  const loading = document.createElement('div')

  loading.setAttribute("class", "lds-ring")

  newCat.appendChild(loading);
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const emptyDiv = document.createElement('div');
    loading.appendChild(emptyDiv);
  }

  /* Loading */

  newCat.setAttribute("id", idCounter++);
  //Diplay spinner here
  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    newCat.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgUrl + ")";
  };
  img.src = imgUrl;
  catBoard.appendChild(newCat);

}
```